# Can't type in input element of React application

Tags: input, element

I am creating a react application that is a replica of frogger and I have a form included for when you get a high score to input your name.  But you can't type in the input box, no letters show up.  Below is my code for the game over/high score divs:

```
      {this.state.collision ? <div >Game Over! {this.checkHighScore() ?
        <Modal
        isOpen={true}
        style={customStyles}
        >
         <div >
           New High Score!
           <form style={{zIndex: '9999'}}>
           <input type="text" style={{zIndex: '1', color: 'black'}} onChange={(e) => this.onNameChange(e)} type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
           <input type="submit" text="Submit" onClick={(e) => this.highScoreSubmit(e)}></input>

           </form>
         </div>

        </Modal>
        :
        <div></div>
      }</div> : <div></div>}
```

As you can see I'm calling an onChange to store input value in state.  I've tried console.log in the onchange function, but it's not registering any input.  Also I've tried playing with z-index and making sure the color is black.  It seems like something is interfering with event functions for some reason, but not sure what that would be.  Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to change `onChange={(e) => this.onNameChange(e)}` to `onChange={(e) => this.onNameChange(e.target.value)}` This is because you are passing an *event* to `this.onNameChange`, instead of a string.

In the future, don't hesitate to console.log things out. You knew it had something to do with your onChange method, so the next steps would be 1.) to find out if it is firing, and if e is what you expect, and 2.) to follow that through the call to `this.onNameChange`, logging from within that method to ensure it is being executed with the correct arguments.

Comment: That didn't help anything.  There's no text I can see when typing in the input field.  And trying your way and my way there doesn't seem to be any events registering when I'm typing in the input field either.